# What is the React Native version compatible with android api16?

Tags: react-native, version

I install react native and created a sample project. but it cannot be run on android version prior to android 6. so i created project with earlier version. following errors occurred. please help.

This is my installation section.

```
C:\react>npm i -g rninit
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\rninit -> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
de_modules\rninit\index.js
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- rninit@0.1.1
  +-- chalk@1.1.3
  | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
  | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
  | | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
  | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
  | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
  +-- prompt@0.2.14
  | +-- pkginfo@0.4.0
  | +-- read@1.0.7
  | | `-- mute-stream@0.0.7
  | +-- revalidator@0.1.8
  | +-- utile@0.2.1
  | | +-- async@0.2.10
  | | +-- deep-equal@1.0.1
  | | +-- i@0.3.5
  | | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
  | | | `-- minimist@0.0.8
  | | +-- ncp@0.4.2
  | | `-- rimraf@2.6.1
  | |   `-- glob@7.1.2
  | |     +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0
  | |     +-- inflight@1.0.6
  | |     | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
  | |     +-- inherits@2.0.3
  | |     +-- minimatch@3.0.4
  | |     | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.7
  | |     |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.2
  | |     |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
  | |     +-- once@1.4.0
  | |     `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  | `-- winston@0.8.3
  |   +-- colors@0.6.2
  |   +-- cycle@1.0.3
  |   +-- eyes@0.1.8
  |   +-- isstream@0.1.2
  |   +-- pkginfo@0.3.1
  |   `-- stack-trace@0.0.10
  `-- semver@5.3.0
```

This is project initialization

```
 C:\react>rninit init TestProject --source react-native@0.1.1
    This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\react\TestP
    roject
    Installing react-native package from npm...

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\R
    oaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-nativ
    e@0.1.1"
    npm ERR! node v6.10.3
    npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
    npm ERR! code ETARGET

    npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: react-native@0.1.1
    npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
    npm ERR! notarget 0.0.0, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2,
     0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.3.10, 0.3.11, 0.4.0, 0.4.1,
    0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.5.0-rc1, 0.5.0, 0.6.0-rc, 0.6.0, 0.7.0-rc, 0.7.0-rc.2, 0.
    7.1, 0.8.0-rc, 0.8.0-rc.2, 0.8.0, 0.9.0-rc, 0.9.0, 0.10.0-rc, 0.10.0, 0.11.0-rc,
     0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0-rc, 0.11.3, 0.11.4, 0.12.0, 0.13.0-rc, 0
    .13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.14.0-rc, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0-rc, 0.14.2, 0.15.0, 0.1
    6.0-rc, 0.16.0, 0.17.0-rc, 0.17.0, 0.18.0-rc, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0-rc, 0.19.0,
     0.20.0-rc1, 0.20.0, 0.21.0-rc, 0.21.0, 0.22.0-rc, 0.22.0-rc3, 0.22.0-rc4, 0.22.
    0-rc5, 0.22.0, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.23.0-rc1, 0.23.0-rc3, 0.23.0-rc4, 0.24.0-rc, 0.
    24.0-rc1, 0.23.0, 0.24.0-rc2, 0.24.0-rc3, 0.23.1, 0.24.0-rc4, 0.24.0-rc5, 0.25.0
    -rc, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.26.0-rc, 0.25.1, 0.26.0, 0.27.0-rc, 0.26.1, 0.26.2, 0.27.
    0-rc1, 0.27.0-rc2, 0.26.3, 0.27.0-rc3, 0.27.0, 0.28.0-rc.0, 0.27.1, 0.27.2, 0.28
    .0, 0.29.0-rc.0, 0.29.0-rc.1, 0.29.0-rc.2, 0.29.0-rc.3, 0.30.0-rc.0, 0.29.0, 0.2
    9.1, 0.29.2, 0.30.0, 0.31.0-rc.0, 0.31.0-rc.1, 0.31.0, 0.32.0-rc.0, 0.33.0-rc.0,
     0.32.0, 0.33.0-rc.1, 0.32.1, 0.33.0, 0.34.0-rc.0, 0.33.1, 0.34.0, 0.35.0-rc.0,
    0.34.1, 0.36.0-rc.0, 0.35.0, 0.36.0-rc.1, 0.36.0, 0.37.0-rc.0, 0.36.1, 0.37.0-rc
    .2, 0.37.0-rc.3, 0.37.0-rc.4, 0.37.0, 0.38.0-rc.0, 0.38.0-rc.1, 0.39.0-rc.0, 0.3
    8.0, 0.39.0, 0.40.0-rc.0, 0.38.1, 0.40.0-rc.1, 0.39.1, 0.40.0-rc.2, 0.39.2, 0.40
    .0, 0.41.0-rc.0, 0.41.0-rc.1, 0.42.0-rc.0, 0.41.0, 0.42.0-rc.1, 0.41.1, 0.41.2,
    0.42.0-rc.2, 0.42.0-rc.3, 0.42.0, 0.43.0-rc.0, 0.43.0-rc.1, 0.43.0-rc.2, 0.42.2,
     0.43.0-rc.3, 0.42.3, 0.43.0-rc.4, 0.44.0-rc.0, 0.43.0, 0.43.1, 0.43.2, 0.43.3,
    0.43.4, 0.44.0, 0.45.0-rc.0, 0.45.0-rc.1, 0.44.1, 0.44.2, 0.45.0-rc.2
    npm ERR! notarget
    npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
    npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
    npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\react\TestProject\npm-debug.log

    `npm install --save react-native@0.1.1` failed
```

what are the versions that are compatible for each android API s.Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum SDK for Android is 4.1 (API 16) and for iOS >= iOS 7.0.

Here is the official document [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e2841c05b4bc67aad90854c7013b278ca4abe03a)

**Update:**
As of 9th Aug 2021, it is Android 5.0 - API 21 and iOS 11.0
[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements)

Comment: what version of react native i should install to make an android app that can run on API 16

Comment: Here is the version I am using `react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.2` You can try this

Comment: Here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html 
it says 
3. Install the Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK 

Android Studio installs the most recent Android SDK by default. React Native, however, requires the Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK. can't we run app build from marshmallow in lower api levels. i mean if build an app with current version can we run it on jellybean?

Comment: Thank You. I figured it out. It works on lower api levels also.

Comment: @NeshanManilka does it work on high API levels also? ie Android 8.0?